# How to set GOBIN automatically

Tags: go, environment-variables

working my go project i need to
`set GOPATH=D:\projects\go\my project`
and then
`set GOBIN=D:\projects\go\my project\bin`
that is okey

then working on an other project same process a gain
so is there is away of setting only GOPATH
and automatically GOBIN becomes GOPATH\bin

Comment: take a look at https://golang.org/doc/install

Comment: @AhmedOzmaan that is just a bad tutorial. Follow the official guide : [golang install](https://golang.org/doc/install). You don't set `GOPATH` or `GOBIN` for each project. You set it once to a general "go" folder. As longs as the contents of this folder follow go conventions, everything will work. `GOPATH` contains `src`, `bin`, `pkg`. `src` contains source files and should be structured in this way : `version-control/account-name/repository`. For example `github.com/ahmed/my-project`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`GOBIN` should by default be `GOPATH/bin`, so you don't have to do anything

See "[`GOPATH` environment variable](https://golang.org/cmd/go/)"

> `DIR` is a directory listed in the `GOPATH`
>
> If the `GOBIN` environment variable is set, commands are installed to the directory it names instead of DIR/bin

Comment: i'm new to  go working on this tutorial   [link](https://youtu.be/SPEv_70RnKo), creating new project i have to  set  GOPATH and GOBIN with my new project that is in the documentation  isn't it?, then working an other  project i need to do like that again, again and again. so searching simple way to do that, do you understood me know

Comment: @AhmedOzmaan Yes, I understand. If you have set `GOPATH`, don't set `GOBIN`: its default value will be `GOPATH/bin`.

Comment: What if my `GOPATH` has multiple directories? Which `GOBIN` do I get?

Comment: @Alexandr The first one. Like packages in https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-GOPATH_environment_variable: "Go searches each directory listed in GOPATH to find source code, but new packages are always downloaded into the first directory in the list. "